# What's the complexity of my program for LCM?

Tags: c, algorithm, complexity-theory

Given below is a program to find LCM of variable number of numbers.

for ex: if i have to find lcm of 3,9,13 then it executes as follows:
lcm(1,3)
lcm(3,9)
lcm(9,13)

All I want to know is what is the complexity of this program. Is it O(n) or O(n^2). Can you also tell me that why it is so?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(int x,int y)
{
    int n;
    if(x>y)
        n=y;
    else
        n=x;

    while(n>=0){
        if(x%n==0 && y%n==0){
            return n;
            break;
        }
        n--;
}
    return 1;
}

int lcm(int a,int b)
{
    return a*b/gcd(a,b);
}

int main()
{
    int tot,i,l=1;
    int n[10];
    printf("Enter the total numbers:");
    scanf("%d",&tot);
    if(tot>10 || tot<2){
        printf("Sorry invalid inputs");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter the numbers one by one:");
    for(i=0;i<tot;i++)
        scanf("%d",&n[i]);

    for(i=0;i<tot;i++){
        l=lcm(l,n[i]);
    }

    printf("The LCM is %d",l);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: What is `n` in your case? Btw. you can optimize by leaving out the first `lcm` since `lcm(1,x) = x`

Comment: n is the total number of numbers of whom the lcm is to be found

Comment: What is 'x % 0'? Where is the break leading after the return? Anyway, if you have an algorithm that is composed of repeatedly applying another algorithm to a sequence, the complexity is the length of the sequence multiplied by the complexity of the sub-algorithm. In order not to provide spoilers, I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: Your GCD algorithm isn't the same as the one Euclid found several thousand years ago — and is a lot less efficient.  Your code is approximately O(N) where N = max(x, y) for a single evaluation of GDC or LCM.  The Euclid algorithm is sub-linear (faster).

Comment: so ignoring the gcd algorithm which could have been faster(euclid's) the complexity is O(n)?

Comment: Somebody told me the complexity of this program is O(n^2) because suppose there are 3 numbers then it will run the for loop 3 times and each time it will call the gcd so total number of runs is 3^2=9

Comment: @svetaketu The body of the for loop will be executed `n` times, in each iteration 1 call to `lcm` is made. In total: `n * 1 = n` calls. Where do you see the `n^2`?

Comment: Recommended reading: [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis/23594#23594)

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your `gcd` method (which is also the complexity of the lcm method) is O(n), where n is `max(x, y)`. This is because in the worst case x and y are coprime, which means n will have to decrement to 1. Euclid's GCD algorithm is faster: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: ok..i am getting it but suppose that i have to find the lcm of 5 numbers then the for loop in main will call lcm function N=5 times so the complexity of the whole program here is O(N*n) where n=max(x,y)?

Answer (score 0):

When you tun a single test case then it is O(n) complexity.

Reason

For calculating LCM you call a*b/gcd(a,b) which further calls gcd(a,b)

in gcd(a,b) function you make a simple while loop which did modulus of the greater number with smaller one till it becomes perfectly divisible from both numbers by decreasing each time the value by one. so it is O(n) where n is the smaller one between two numbers

When you run with a number of test cases then for each test case it will take O(n)

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like the following:

[image]